# Cannot configure quilt on mac for csipsimple

Tags: macos, date, sed, quilt

I am trying to configure quilt to be able to do a make and make install so as to build csipsimple (http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild) on mac, however, i run into below issue when i try to configure quilt. I have macports installed.

```
Sorry, you have a version of sed which doesn't understand constructs
of the form (foo|bar).  quilt needs it.  If you have access to
a version of sed which does understand such constructs, you can supply
its path with the '--with-sed=' option.
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

install gsed with

```
sudo port install gsed
```

then

```
./configure --with-sed=gsed
```